# Opencart 2.2.x ssl for all request

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, opencart

i install opencart lastest version and i wanna enable all ssl for url

In admin set SSL enable

in config.php both admin and category change to https

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but when url is not SEO it work so url with SEO it not work 
the url will be 
[https://www.localhost/index.php?*route*=desktops/mac](https://www.localhost/index.php?_route_=desktops/mac)

how to change to 
https://www.localhost/desktops/mac

Answer (score 4):

I also installed opencart 2.2.

I tried the extension for https but it crashed everything ;(

I found a working solution 3 Steps :

•• 1 •• 
in .htaccess : Added at the end

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} store 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.__your_domain__.com/store/$1 [R,L]
```

•• 2 ••
in config.php in root + admin

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.__your_domain__.com/store/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.__your_domain__.com/store/');
```

---

**** even with https:// in the browser wasn't enough.... in the source every links where http:// ....
**** So i found this last step

---

•• 3 •• 
in system/library/url
Modified http to https and voilà :)

```
public function link($route, $args = '', $secure = false) {
        if ($this->ssl && $secure) {
            $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
        } else {
            $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I just spent and entire night getting this to work hope it helps somebody. I currently have an Opencart 2.2 with SSL/https working for all pages. (good crap what a chore).. I am using the Fastor Theme and have SEO Pack Pro, vQMOD, and several other mods and extensions.

Here's what I did:
1. Install [v2.2.0.x Changes.zip](http://www.randemsystems.com/support/opencart/migrating-your-data-from-opencart-version-2-1-0-x-to-version-2-2-0-0-(test-only)/msg6260/#msg6260)
**DO NOT update VQMOD to 2.6.1** (killed my install)
**DO NOT install VQMOD Manager 3.0** (Also killed my install). 
Just Manually install. Google that if you need to.

2. Then install [this extension](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=26740&filter_search=https&filter_download_id=44)
   No I can't read spanish, but I looked at the xml file and it's setting site_ssl to true in multiple pages as was suggested to do manually somewhere deep in the forums.
   This made it so the checkout/checkout and information pages also worked.
3. Admin panel > Settings > Security > Use SSL
4. Modify .haccess for SEO/SSL/WWW (I got my cert for www of the site because I wanted the whole site to be SSL). Replaces the seo rewrite chunk you should see in your haccess file:

> Blockquote

```
#SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
#If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make    sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=302]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

5. Modify config.php and admin/config.php. Make all http -> https

> Blockquote

```
config.php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/');

admin/config.php

// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'https://www.example.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.example.com/');
```

6. Clear your mod cache and browser cache/temp files before testing.

Other Manual Fixes I made:
**Currency/Currency Fix**
The [currency/currency "fix"](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=164122) didn't work for me. If the currency changer is breaking your SSL you can try that fix or remove it by removing all code in view/common/currency.tpl. Make a backup and then just blank the code.

**Not Loading Images/CSS** 
Try this fix:
I also put in this fix by hand don't know if the v2.2.0 Changes.zip gets this one or not:

> Blockquote

```
SEO/SSL cant load page

Open catalog/controller/startup/startup.php

and after

$this->config->set('config_url', HTTP_SERVER);

add

$this->config->set('config_ssl', HTTPS_SERVER);
```

Comment: This one saved my day  $this->config->set('config_ssl', HTTPS_SERVER);  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed in admin ?
in admin panel > setting > security
enable 
use SSL

Comment: Yes. Enable this. @Pranav Bhatt

Comment: in .htaccess 
RewriteBase /{with your folder name}

Comment: All file is root directory.

Comment: /config.php:

define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://www.example.com/image/');

in both config.php

is admin enable USE seo urls
are u working ssl localhost?

Comment: Done it. In live host not localhost. I write localhost because protected my customer domain.@Pranav Bhatt

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I just did: `https` was showing errors and my add to cart, etc - was not working. I had to enable `ssl` in the site settings from admin, standard, then I checked my `header.tpl` file in notepad and clicked on edit-find `HTTP` and changed two entries to `HTTPS`

```
<meta https-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

and the dir to an image file I had added in the html for the header at an earlier date, which directed it to `http://mywebsite url`.

These two things were causing the error. As soon as I `ftp'd` the file back to the site it worked fine in *Firefox* and *IE*. I'm a complete novice at coding but it was obvious (after ripping a few hairs out) so just check your header files and change every `http` to `https`. And cross your fingers and toes.

Comment: i also changed the config files in site and admin to reflect HTTPS instead of HTTP

Answer (score -1):

It means that install the opencart whitout vqmod and use the solution and then install vqmod